# Backbonejs JST is not defined without Rails

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js-templating, jst

I have one page index.html

I've made page with head:

```
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/json2.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/jquery.lazyload.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/scrollstop.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/backbone.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/backbone/search.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/javascripts/backbone/templates/filter.jst.ejs" type="text/template"></script>
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/backbone/templates/item.jst.ejs" type="text/template"></script>
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/backbone/templates/item_loading.jst.ejs" type="text/template"></script>
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/backbone/templates/more.jst.ejs" type="text/template"></script>
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/backbone/templates/razbor.jst.ejs" type="text/template"></script>
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/backbone/templates/total.jst.ejs" type="text/template"></script>
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/backbone/models/filter.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/backbone/models/filter_value.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/backbone/models/item.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/backbone/models/more.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/backbone/models/razbor.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/backbone/models/search.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/backbone/views/filter_view.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/backbone/views/item_view.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/backbone/views/razbor_view.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/backbone/views/search_view.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/backbone/routers/search_router.js"></script>
```

And chrome tells me:
Uncaught ReferenceError: JST is not defined
    at filter_view.js:4

The line 4:

```
template: JST["backbone/templates/filter"],
```

What should I do without Rails to fix my problem?

Thanks for advises!

Comment: I've inited window.JST = {};
And error has gone.

Comment: I've found that I need ejs.js. But how to initialize JST to have function.